# How to check that in basicHttpBinding client gets data in text format?

Tags: wcf-binding

By default there is no data security in basicHttpBinding, so how to check it ?

we want to check that by default in basicHttpBinding when client gets response from wcf then data travel in plain text not in encrypted form. Actully we have implement some security on it so we also then check data communication in both scenario (default behavior and with security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool such as [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze the messages sent by HTTP from the client machine